# How to correctly grab blob names with whitespaces in azure from az cli

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a user that is putting a lot of whitespaces in their filenames and this is causing a download script to go bad.

To get the names of the blobs I use this:

```
BLOBS=$(az storage blob list --container-name $c \
--account-name $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT  --account-key $AZURE_STORAGE_KEY \
--query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv)
```

What is happening for a blob like `blob with space.pdf` it is getting stored as `[blob\twith\tspace.pdf]` where \t is the tab. When I iterate in an effort to download obviously I can't get at the file.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: you want to download the blobs whose name contains white-space in a container?

Comment: @IvanYang that's right.

Comment: Sorry, got busy with non-programming life for a day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command [az storage blob download-batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download-batch).

I tested it in azure portal, all the blobs including whose name contains white-space are downloaded.

The command:

```
c=container_name
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT=xx
AZURE_STORAGE_KEY=xx

//download the blobs to clouddrive
cd clouddrive

az storage blob download-batch -d . -s $c --account-name $AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT --account-key $AZURE_STORAGE_KEY
```

The test result:

[image]